# HTML table settings not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to tamper with my html table settings to set borders but I think my syntax is wrong. I've looked around online and tried multiple things with no success. Any suggestions?

For example, this code is applied to the first table but does not appear correctly on page.

```
<table BORDER="30" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="3" BORDERCOLOR="00FF00" width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
</table>
```

HTML code is applied here: http://macrorevolution.com/calculators/bmr/

The only table settings that seem to work are "width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;""

```
<?php
$answer = "";
$agev = "";
$feetv = "";
$inchesv = "";
$weightv = "";
$sex = "";
if(isset($_POST['agev']) && isset($_POST['feetv']) && isset($_POST['inchesv']) && isset($_POST['weightv']) && isset($_POST['sex'])) {
    $agev = $_POST['agev'];
    $feetv = $_POST['feetv'];
    $inchesv = $_POST['inchesv'];
    $weightv = $_POST['weightv'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $totalheightv = $inchesv + ($feetv*12);
    $heightcm = $totalheightv*2.54;
    $weightkg = $weightv/2.2;
    if($sex=='male') $answer = 66.47 + (13.75*$weightkg) + (5*$heightcm) - (6.75*$agev);
    if($sex=='female') $answer = 665.09 + (9.56*$weightkg) + (1.84*$heightcm) - (4.67*$agev);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Basal Metabolic Rate Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box pt20">
<table BORDER="30" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="3" BORDERCOLOR="00FF00" width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">
    <h4 style="background: #99FF99;">
<strong>BMR = Basal Metabolic Rate</strong> (similar to RMR = Resting Metabolic Rate). Your BMR represents the number of calories your body burns at rest. Regular routine of cardiovascular exercise can increase your BMR, improving your health and fitness when your body's ability to burn energy gradually slows down.
    </h4>
    </td>
</table>

<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='5' width='80%' font-family:Georgia; font-size:1; class="table" style="margin: 0 auto;" bgcolor="FFFFFF">

    <tr class="calcheading">
        <td colspan="2"><font size="10">MacroRevolution BMR Calculator</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='agev' value="<?php echo $agev; ?>"/>Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow2">
        <td>Height:</td>
        <td align="justify"><input type='text' name='feetv' value="<?php echo $feetv; ?>"/>Ft<input type='text' name='inchesv' value="<?php echo $inchesv; ?>"/>In</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>Weight:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type='text' name='weightv' value="<?php echo $weightv; ?>"/>lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gender">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male
                        <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="submit">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' class="button highlight small" value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td colspan="2">Your BMR is <span style="background-color: #00CC33"><?php echo $answer?></span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>


<table border='0' width='80%' class="table" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">

    <h2 style="background: #99FF66;">Formula for BMR</h2>
    <h4 style="background: #99FF66;">
    If you want to manually calculate your BMR, use the (<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris%E2%80%93Benedict_equation">Harris-Benedict formula</a>) <br> below. <br><br>
Men: BMR=66.47+ (13.75 x W) + (5.0 x H) - (6.75 x A) <br>
Women: BMR=665.09 + (9.56 x W) + (1.84 x H) - (4.67 x A) <br><br>

    W = Weight in kilograms (lbs/2.2)<br>
    H = Height in centimeters (inches x 2.54)<br>
    A = Age in years
    </h4>
    </td>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
```

Comment: Hm, `XHTML 1.0 Transitional`? What are you transitioning from? But suffice to say: you are mixing up attributes and style data. Try to run your HTML [through a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) when you encounter problems, it will likely tell you what some of those problems are.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks Wrikken, I'm not sure what the standard XHTML settings are but when I make a new php page in dreamweaver cs5 it has that markup. What should I change it to? I will test the validator now

Comment: Depends on the exact use, but for new pages I'd recommand HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). Easier to remember the doctype declaration too :)

Comment: Just pass your page to a validator, you'll understand everything. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks! Will start using the standard HTML5. Regarding the attribute/style data, which one should I be using? Alot of help sites confuse me because I am not using css for my tables.

Comment: I just copied just the table-part which is behind '<body>
<div class="box pt20">' into w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_cellspacing) and it seems to work fine. Therewith I think there is something else not working.

Comment: @Meru I also tried isolating the code as shown here: http://rgoo.co/calculators/bmr-calculator.php   everything seems to work fine but I'm not sure why it doesn't work on http://macrorevolution.com/calculators/bmr/

Comment: @RyanGoo: [validate whole pages, not snippets](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmacrorevolution.com%2Fcalculators%2Fbmr%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: I agree, you need to check the other parts of the page too, due to the snippets seem to be the same, I just doublechecked. Trying another Doctype seems also a good try I think.

Comment: Thank you all for valuable information, I truly do appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid HTML attributes like `border="30" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#00ff00"` and use CSS instead:

```
<style>
  table {
    border: 30px solid #00ff00;
  }
</style>
```

Even better, move the styles to another file

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">`